# Count of result of a sql query based on values

Tags: sql, count

The result of a temp table in sql is like:

```
ServiceType
-----------
E                             
I                             
I                             
E                             
I                             
D                             
I 
D
E
```

I want the count of above result something like this (where I-Imp,E-Exp,D-Dom):

```
Type   Count
------------
Exp     3
Imp     4
Dom     2
```

Can anyone please suggest me the best way to achieve this? I am trying to do this by creating an other temp table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT CASE ServiceType 
       WHEN 'I' THEN 'Imp' 
       WHEN 'E' THEN 'Exp' 
       WHEN 'D' THEN 'Dom' END AS Type
, COUNT(ServiceType) AS `Count`
FROM MyTable GROUP BY ServiceType
```

Result:

```
| TYPE | COUNT |
----------------
|  Dom |     2 |
|  Exp |     3 |
|  Imp |     4 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2da74b/4)

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
select type, count(type) from table
group by type.
```