# Query that returns count of values based on primary key

Tags: mysql

I currently have a two MySql tables in this format where Student.Type references Type.TypeName

```
    Student:
    CenterID | StudentName | Type
    --------- ------------- ------
    1        | Abc         | A
    1        | Def         | B
    2        | Ebc         | A
    2        | Agc         | A
    2        | Abe         | D
    3        | Gtc         | A
    3        | Hic         | B

    Type:
    TypeName
    --------
    A
    B
    C
    D
```

The output i need is in this form:

```
    CenterID | A | B | C | D 
    --------- --- --- --- ---
    1        | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
    2        | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1
    3        | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
```

I have found a similar problem but i cannot manually add each case to the query as and when "Type" changes.

[Count of result of a sql query based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272148/count-of-result-of-a-sql-query-based-on-values)

Any kind of assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
select centerId, 
       sum(type = 'A') as A,
       sum(type = 'B') as B,
       sum(type = 'C') as C,
       sum(type = 'D') as D
from student
group by centerId
```

Comment: He's fast. Gotta give 'im that.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. If i add E to type, then I have to manually add an additional case. Isn't there any way where the query scans the values of the primary key?